# permission denied on key while trying to change the swappiness- Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, swap

How to change the swappiness of my 12.10 Ubuntu System from 60 to 10.

Getting response as permission denied:-

Steps - I am following are below:

neeta@neeta-desktop:~$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
neeta@neeta-desktop:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness=10
sysctl: permission denied on key 'vm.swappiness'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use sudo before your command.

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

then type in your password

Comment: did not worked for me, I was using openVz vps